# Assets 1.2.2 to 2.0.1 upgrade fails

Tags: assets

Here's the output on the first try:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: 4:Adult Discipleship
Filename: assets/upd.assets.php
Line Number: 712

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: 4:Adult Discipleship
Filename: assets/upd.assets.php

Line Number: 712
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: 1:rotating
Filename: assets/upd.assets.php
```

...ad infinitum.

When I refresh the page I get:

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1146
Table 'ee_local.exp_assets' doesn't exist
ALTER TABLE exp_assets MODIFY COLUMN file_path VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
Filename: /Users/chris/Sites/third_party/assets/upd.assets.php
Line Number: 390
```

Comment: Assets 2.0.2 is release if you want to give it a go.

Comment: Please direct bug reports directly to developers - thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The undefined index errors should be fixed in an upcoming 2.0.2 release.  I think that'll remove the error that follows what you're seeing.

-Lisa

Comment: 2.0.2 was a success. I'm really liking it. Great work!